# Create a DataFrame from a dictionary of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of DataFrames, where the keys are assumed to be meaningful:

```
In [32]: x = pd.DataFrame(dict(foo=[1,2,3], bar=[4,5,6])).set_index('foo')
In [33]: y = pd.DataFrame(dict(foo=[7,8,9], bar=[10,11,12])).set_index('foo')
In [34]: z = dict(x=x, y=y)
```

Which looks like:

```
In [43]: x
Out[43]: 
     bar
foo     
1      4
2      5
3      6

In [44]: y
Out[44]: 
     bar
foo     
7     10
8     11
9     12
```

Is there a nice way to get the following DataFrame:

```
    foo  bar
x   1    4
    2    5
    3    6
y   7    10
    8    11
    9    12
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for this, and the keys of the dictionary will automatically be used for a new index level:

```
In [6]: z = dict(x=x, y=y)

In [7]: pd.concat(z)
Out[7]:
       bar
  foo
x 1      4
  2      5
  3      6
y 7     10
  8     11
  9     12
```

You can also give this new index level a name using the `names` argument of `concat` (eg `names=['key']`).

Comment: Every time I discover something new about pandas I love it more and more. Bonus points for the `names=` part too.

Comment: The names option of this yields "ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex." for me.

Comment: `pd.concat(z, names=['key'])` works fine for me. What version of pandas are you using? If you still have a problem with, please open a new question.

Comment: pd.concat(z, names=['key']) is a nice attempt! This post is really helpful for me.